# Google Spreadsheet ARRAYFORMULA() with INDIRECT() and ROW()

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet in which I enter daily income and expenses:

[image: Daily Income and Expenses]

On another sheet, I am trying to calculate the monthly income and expenses for every month:

[image: Monthly income and expenses]

I am using this formula to calculate the monthly income ('s1' is the daily sheet):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(FILTER(s1!B2:B; MONTH(s1!A2:A)=MONTH(INDIRECT("A" & ROW())))))
```

but it does work for the whole column.

Is there any way to make the arrayformula work with the indirect and row functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would work as a SUMIF instead - try:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,SUMIF(MONTH(s1!A2:A),MONTH(A2:A),s1!B2:B)))`